# Twitter AP truncates tweets after tweet_mode: "extended"

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

thats pretty much it. 
I used this snippet to run the query and tweet_mode: "extended" was working fine when the query was in form of 
`{q: "from:" + body.name}`
but then I needed to switch to do 
`{q: "about:" + body.name}` and I got tweets back but this time all of them were truncated. It did fetch tweets about the username that I specified...

Any ideas? help would be greatly appreciated ^^

Comment: *and I did have tweet_mode: "extended" on both of them
I'm also hitting the search/tweets endpoint